# Google Inbox: как отключить цитирование текста в письмах?

Tags: php, email

Когда отправляются 2 однотипных письма, которые отличаются, например, несколькими строками, то inbox сворачивает одинаковые блоки в "цитируемый текст", тем самым убивая весь внешний вид письма.

Какие есть способы этого избежать?

Собственно пример:
[image: письмо в inbox]

Answer (score 1):

В основном почтовые сервисы, тем более `Google`, группирует письма не по тексту в письме а по полю "Тема сообщения" и, если ваши автоматически генерируемые письма имеют одинаковую тему, понятно что будет группировать... 
Для решения данной проблемы вы можете к теме письма всегда добавлять , например, Дату/Время отправки и тема автоматических сообщений всегда (почти :) )  будет разной и у получателей уже не будет цепочка цитирования.

Comment: у него проблема не с формированием цепочки, а с тем что в цепочках повторяющиеся блоки в разных письмах "схлопываются". Например, Вы напишете несколько писем, начинающихся с "Привет, Вася, это автоматическое письмо.", а дальше текст будет разным всё время. И вот этот блок повторяющийся будет выведен только в первом письме - в остальных он будет свёрнут в кнопочку с многоточием (как на картинке в вопросе). Хотя, если разделить на разные цепочки (как Вы предлагаете), то проблема косвенным образом решится сама.